# Besides C++. is there a strongly typed language that has pointers, and does pointers have any influence on strongly typed languages?

Tags: java, c++, pointers, strong-typing

I was working on java, and then i thought about if Java would still be a strongly typed language if pointers would be introduced into it.

C++ is a strongly typed language, but it has a few properties that is the properties of a weakly typed language, like the "auto" variable.

When checking C++ i think there's no need for me to discuss whether java would still be a strongly typed language or not when pointers are introduced into it.

One of the biggest differences in java and C++ are pointers, and if both of them are strongly typed, but one of them doesn't have pointers and the other has it, i think it doesnt have any influence.

Hope you can help me with this "problem" i have, thank you!

Comment: "that is the properties of a weakly typed language, like the "auto" variable." It is **required**, that the actual type of `auto`, needs to be resolved at **compile time** (the `auto` variable type doesn't persist in compiled code - it's merely syntactic sugar). Hence, it's **not** possible to have code similar to `auto var; if (runtimeCondition) var = 1; else var = "test";`, like you may be able to do in weakly typed languages.

Comment: [Golang](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1).

Comment: memory pointer is itself a type, so its existence is IMHO implying strongly typed language. You can have probably very weakly typed pointers (something like `void*` in C and C++), but I would be surprised if they would be useful for anything without the strong type features, like casting to other type, etc... Seems to me like pointers without type are basically totally useless and pointers with type dynamically deducted/assigned at runtime are far from assembly-like pointer=unsigned num, more like smart reference having extra bits of information somewhere to deduct the correct type at runtime.

Comment: Actually it may be claimed that Java do have pointers, i.e. any Java variable, except for builtin types, is actually work exactly as C++ pointer. It just dereferenced using `.` instead of `->`, that's all.